Confusion while proving Leibniz Integral Rule
I'm trying to prove Leibniz's Integral Rule with the Chain Rule :
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(x, y) dy = g(x, b(x)) b'(x) - g(x, a(x)) a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x, y) dy $$
Let $h(u, v, w) := \int_{u}^{v} g(w, y) dy$ then by the Chain Rule we have :
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(x, y) dy = \frac{d}{dx} h(a(x), b(x), x) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial a} \frac{da}{dx} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial b} \frac{db}{dx} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dx} $$
I understand the first two terms but have no idea why $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$ equals to $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} D_{1} g(x, y) dy$ - since it is only a function of $x$ I think $\frac{dh}{dx}$ should be the exact same with $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$.
Can anyone elaborate that ?

You are confusing yourself by substituting back to $(a(x),b(x),x)$ before taking the partial derivatives.$$\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial w}=\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial w}\int_u^v g(w,y),\mathrm d y$$

I am not sure what you are asking , this is my guess at what your Doubt is.
Consider $h=a^3x^2+5a+7x+9$
We can not talk about $dh/d9$ , because $9$ is a Constant , not a variable.
We can indeed talk about $dh/dx$ , where we implicitly claim that $a$ is a Constant , not a variable , in which Case , we can no longer talk about $dh/da$ , because $a$ is a Constant in our view.
We can alternately talk about $\partial h / \partial x$ , where we implicitly claim that $a$ is a variable , in which Case , we can still talk about $\partial h / \partial a$ , because $a$ is a variable in our view.
In your Example , you have $\partial h / \partial a$ ( you are claiming there are other independent variables ) , then you must use $\partial h / \partial x$
Here , you can not have $dh/dx$ ( you are claiming that only $x$ is the independent variable ) because that will give conflicts within $dh/dx$ , $dh/da$ , $\partial h / \partial a$ , $\partial h / \partial x$
Let me know whether that was your Doubt , else I can revise the answer or entirely delete it.

I understood the difference between $\frac{dh}{dx}$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$ but still cannot understand why $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} D_{1} g(x, y) dy$.

@Vue  see Corollary 12.4 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf.

It is because $\frac{\partial~~}{\partial w}\!\int_u^v g(w,y)\,\mathrm d y=\int_u^v\!\frac{\partial~~}{\partial w}g(w,y)\,\mathrm d y$

Let $u=a(x), v=b(x), w=x$.
$\qquad\begin{align}
&\quad\dfrac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm d x}\int_u^v g(w,y)\,\mathrm d y
\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm d x}\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial u}\int_u^v g(w,y)\,\mathrm d y+\dfrac{\mathrm d v}{\mathrm d x}\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial v}\int_u^v g(w,y)\,\mathrm d y+\dfrac{\mathrm d w}{\mathrm d x}\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial w}\int_u^v g(w,y)\,\mathrm d y
\\[2ex]&=-\dfrac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm d x}~g(w,u)+\dfrac{\mathrm d v}{\mathrm d x}~g(w,v)+\dfrac{\mathrm d w}{\mathrm d x}\int_u^v\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial w}g(w,y)\,\mathrm d y
\\[2ex]&=-a'(x)~g(x,a(x))+b'(x)~g(x,b(x))+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\mathrm D_1g(x, y)\,\mathrm dy
\end{align}$
